# Using type script to filter two arrays based on certain items in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an two arrrays and need to figure out which part of array2 is in array1 based on an item in each.

The sample for the arrays are:

```
var array1 = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"},
    {"myId": 3, "text": "d"},
    {"myId": 4, "text": "e"},
    {"myId": 5, "text": "f"}];


var array2 = [
    {"myId": 1, "value": "1x1"},
    {"myId": 1, "value": "2x2"},
    {"myId": 2, "value": "3x3"},
    {"myId": 6, "value": "4x4"},
    {"myId": 7, "value": "5x5"}];
```

I need to get the objects of array1 that are included in array2 based on equaling myId from each array.

So the results should be an array like so:

```
var result = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"}];
```

I have tried using filter and include but can't seem to get it right exactly.

Comment: This can't be done in a robust way if there are duplicate ids. Ids should always be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to collect all the `myId` from `array2`, and filter `array1` based on the values:

```js
const array1 = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"},
    {"myId": 3, "text": "d"},
    {"myId": 4, "text": "e"},
    {"myId": 5, "text": "f"}];


const array2 = [
    {"myId": 1, "value": "1x1"},
    {"myId": 1, "value": "2x2"},
    {"myId": 2, "value": "3x3"},
    {"myId": 6, "value": "4x4"},
    {"myId": 7, "value": "5x5"}];
    
const ids = new Set(array2.map(item => item.myId));
const filteredArray1 = array1.filter(item => ids.has(item.myId));
console.log(filteredArray1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an exact match (for example you need to have 2 values with `myId = 1` in order to have the same number of values in the result) you can do it in this way:

```js
var array1 = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c2"}, // no exact match --> not filtered
    {"myId": 3, "text": "d"},
    {"myId": 4, "text": "e"},
    {"myId": 5, "text": "f"}
 ];


var array2 = [
    {"myId": 1, "value": "1x1"},
    {"myId": 1, "value": "2x2"},
    {"myId": 2, "value": "3x3"},
    {"myId": 6, "value": "4x4"},
    {"myId": 7, "value": "5x5"}];
    

let result = array1.filter(a => array2.some(b => a.myId == b.myId))

console.log(result)
```

If you need an exact match instead:

```js
var array1 = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c2"}, // exact match --> filtered
    {"myId": 3, "text": "d"},
    {"myId": 4, "text": "e"},
    {"myId": 5, "text": "f"}];


var array2 = [
    {"myId": 1, "value": "1x1"},
    {"myId": 1, "value": "2x2"},
    {"myId": 2, "value": "3x3"},
    {"myId": 6, "value": "4x4"},
    {"myId": 7, "value": "5x5"}];
    
function filterForId(arr1, arr2) { 
  let filtered = []
  return arr1.filter(a => {
    let found = arr2.find(b => !filtered.includes(b) && a.myId == b.myId);
    if (found) { filtered.push(found); return true; }
    return false;
  });
}

let result = filterForId(array1, array2);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, though the runtime might be terrible.

```
array1.filter((element) => array2.some((el) => element.myId === el.myId))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
    {"myId": 1, "text": "a"},
    {"myId": 1, "text": "b"},
    {"myId": 2, "text": "c"},
    {"myId": 3, "text": "d"},
    {"myId": 4, "text": "e"},
    {"myId": 5, "text": "f"}];


var array2 = [
    {"myId": 1, "value": "1x1"},
    {"myId": 1, "value": "2x2"},
    {"myId": 2, "value": "3x3"},
    {"myId": 6, "value": "4x4"},
    {"myId": 7, "value": "5x5"}];
    
const result = [];

for (const element of array1) {
  const idIsInOther = array2.find(a => a.myId === element.myId);
  if (idIsInOther) {
    result.push(element);
  }
}

console.log(result)
```